# EC2 instance with Docker Container connecting to RDS Database from shell but not from website

Tags: postgresql, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, amazon-rds

I created an application that I wanted to deploy online.
The app is stored in a directory `app` and I have another directory called `nginx` which contains an nginx server that I use as a reverse proxy to deploy the app with HTTPS.
I use an AWS EC2 insance as the server and an RDS database using Postgres to store data, the two instances are connected with the vpc and all the securities groups has been created.
To deploy the app I decided to containerize the application using Docker, creating two containers, one for the application and one for the nginx reverse proxy. Using `docker-compose up` the application is correctly built and the site can be used online deployed on the EC2 server.
The problem appears when I try to use any function that involves the application talking with the database, I tried to log the response from the database and got:

```
error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "<EC2 Private IPv4>", user "masteruser", database "postgres", no encryption
nodeserver_1  |     at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/usr/src/app/server/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
nodeserver_1  |     at Parser.handlePacket (/usr/src/app/server/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
nodeserver_1  |     at Parser.parse (/usr/src/app/server/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
nodeserver_1  |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/server/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
nodeserver_1  |     at Socket.emit (node:events:519:28)
nodeserver_1  |     at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12)
nodeserver_1  |     at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:510:3)
nodeserver_1  |     at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:390:5)
nodeserver_1  |     at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
nodeserver_1  |   length: 162,
nodeserver_1  |   severity: 'FATAL',
nodeserver_1  |   code: '28000',
nodeserver_1  |   detail: undefined,
nodeserver_1  |   hint: undefined,
nodeserver_1  |   position: undefined,
nodeserver_1  |   internalPosition: undefined,
nodeserver_1  |   internalQuery: undefined,
nodeserver_1  |   where: undefined,
nodeserver_1  |   schema: undefined,
nodeserver_1  |   table: undefined,
nodeserver_1  |   column: undefined,
nodeserver_1  |   dataType: undefined,
nodeserver_1  |   constraint: undefined,
nodeserver_1  |   file: 'auth.c',
nodeserver_1  |   line: '543',
nodeserver_1  |   routine: 'ClientAuthentication'
nodeserver_1  | }
```

I tried to add the IP to the `pg_hba.conf` file inside the EC2 instance (I was not sure that this would work as the database that I want to connect with is an independent instance), but nothing changed, I tried to add security groups to the RDS instance but nothing works.

The strange thing happened when I tried to access the Database from the EC2 instance by using the shell, even if I use it inside a container I am able to connect to the database using `psql` command.

So the problem seems to appear only when I am trying to use the database from the application client, not from the terminal.

Comment: It's hard to tell not going over your whole configuration. Moreover, it's very easy to make a mistake if you're doing everything manually and not using a terraform-like tool to deploy to aws... First thing to check is your instance firewall and if it allows connections from docker containers... Depends on what ami you're using. If you try to `psql` from a container, not your host, and it fails, then I'd bet it's your firewall

Comment: What if try `PGSSLMODE=disable psql ....`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0. (First and foremost) Please SHOW YOUR CODE and configuration. Guessing is hard.
1. Do not use pg-protocol, use one of [well known PostgreSQL drivers for Javascript/Typescript](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/List_of_drivers), like [postgres.js](https://github.com/porsager/postgres) or [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres).
2. If error message says `no encryption`, make sure your driver supports SSL connections and connection is established in encrypted mode.